# problem using isAlive(),Interrupt() and stop() methods of a Thread inside ExecuterService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

i have found that isAlive() method is not working when executing a thread using ExecuterService.
And interrupt() and stop() method is also not working.
The code i used:

```
Thread t1=new Thread(()->{
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch(InterruptedExeception ie){
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("It's Done");
});
ExecuterService excuter=Executers.newSingleThreadExecuter();
excuter.execute(t1);
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
Thread.sleep(2000);
t1.interrupt();
t1.stop();
```

My expected output is :

> true
>   Interrupted

Actual output is :

> false
>   It's Done

I need reason for this behavior. And I want to know what is the solution for the problem and **how I use these methods when a Thread is running inside a ThreadPool.**

Comment: When you invoke `excuter.execute(t1);`, it's not actually running on `t1`, but rather another thread that's created (or possibly even the executing thread). So, interrupting `t1` without invoking `t1.start();` is futile.

Comment: ok, but how do i check if the thread is alive or not

Comment: You don't. The thread that's executing the task isn't directly exposed to you. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: hey i want to make a  timer that accpet a task and we can start and cancel and again start when ever we want using start() and cancel() method. for delaying task i am using Thread.sleep() method and for cancelling i use interrupt method and to check if the thread is running or not before cancelling and restarting i use isAlive() method.

Comment: I recommend looking into `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: yeah i already looked but, i wnat to stop the thread not the whole threadpool. In sheduledExecuter there is only one method cancel() to cancel the task but it cancel the whole ExecuterService. so, i made this on my own.

Comment: You wouldn't stop the whole thread pool. You can submit a task and it would return a `ScheduledFuture<?>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `stop()` method does not work. You can't stop threads like this. A thread needs to opt into allowing itself to be stopped; you'd for example update a (volatile, or AtomicBoolean-style) boolean, and the thread runs a loop, and on each loop, checks that boolean; if it's false, it ends. There is no way to stop arbitrary threads in their tracks. At all. You can google for information about why Thread.stop is deprecated (and effectively doesn't work at all anymore, even though the method is still around, primarily as vehicle for the documentation on why you can't do that anymore).
2. Threads implement runnable, which is why you're even allowed to pass that thread to the executor method, but the entire thread infra isn't being used at all. You should update this code to be Runnable r = () -> { ... } and pass that. Your code as written is misleading you into thinking that's the thread that is being run. It's not, which is why you're getting `false` for `.isAlive()`.
3. Executors as a rule don't expose the way they do the job, they just do it. If you want to check if the job is running, set a (volatile, or AtomicBoolean) boolean to true upon entry, and to false upon exit. Alternatively, don't bother with an executor service, just start your thread, if you really want to use thread functionalities such as `.isAlive()`.

Comment: Re. 1, that boolean already exists, it's `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

Comment: In my Timer(see the above disscussion in comments) i use interrupt() method to stop a thread that is in sleep for some delay by using return statement inside catch block of InterruptedExeption.

Comment: I used boolean isRunning to check weather it is running or not. That is put to true when start of run() and put to false in end. But, my problem is how do i cancel my Timer from executing task.

Comment: @assylias that's not really the correct usage. You _CAN_ use interrupt as an ersatz 'stop the presses' flag, but it is not defined to do that (hence the name). For example, if the platform allows it, any thread that is currently in wait mode, waiting for disk or network traffic, will abort (throwing some flavour of IOException) if you interrupt the thread. It is plausible you want to cause an I/O op to be aborted without then ending that entire thread.

Comment: @Logesh-0304 any method that waits for things and is defined to throw InterruptedException can be interrupted. Use the interrupt mechanism to abort the wait, and use a boolean flag to signal what you want it to do. For other 'waiting' methods, such as, say, reading files or sending bytes across a network, it's up the OS and the VM whether interrupting it does anything. If it works at all, you'll get an IOException of some flavour.

Answer (score 1):

`t1` is not a thread.

`t1` is a `Thread` instance, but a `Thread` instance is not the same thing as a thread, and the way you are using `t1`, no thread is ever created. Think of a `Thread` instance as a *[handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing))* that you use to create and control a thread.  The thread would be created if your program called `t1.start()`, and then the `t1.isAlive()` and `t1.interrupt()` and `t1.stop()` calls all would operate on that new thread.

Besides being a `Thread` instance, `t1` also happens to be a `Runnable` instance, which is what the `executer.execute(...)` call wants. Being a `Runnable` just means that `t1` has a `run()` method.  There are various ways that `run()` method could be called:

- You could start the thread, `t1.start()`, in which case, the new thread would call it,
- You could (you *did*) give it to an `Executor`. When you do that, the Executor arranges to have one of its *worker threads* call your `run()` method.
- You could simply call it -- `t1.run()` -- which is no different from calling any other method that your code defines.
- You could pass it to any other library method that wants a `Runnable`. (I don't know how many there are, maybe a lot.)

---

If you want `t1.run()` to be called in a thread that your code can control, then call `t1.start()` to create that thread.  If you want it to be called by an executor service, whose threads you *should not* attempt to control, then do what you did: call `excuter.execute(t1);`

Just don't do both. That probably isn't what you want.

---

P.S., If you want to continue using the Executor service, then you probably should change your declaration of `t1`. Since it only needs to be a `Runnable` in that case, you can write:

```
Thread t1=new Runnable(()->{
    ...
});
```

That way, people reading your code won't scratch their heads and wonder whether you knew what you were doing.